# Split string inside nested list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list like this:

```
 lst = [['one two', 'three'], ['four five', 'six']]
```

I need to make:

```
lst = [['one', 'two', 'three'], ['four', 'five', 'six']]
```

Tried 
`([i[0].split() for i in lst])` 
but it gives only 
`[['one', 'two'], ['four', 'five']]`
Any ideas how to manage it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying this, but you can just join and re-split?

```
>>> [' '.join(x).split() for x in lst]
[['one', 'two', 'three'], ['four', 'five', 'six']]
```

Or, using the equivalent `map` method:

```
>>> list(map(str.split, map(' '.join, lst)))
[['one', 'two', 'three'], ['four', 'five', 'six']]
```